# WebGL transformation matrices in shader or in the application

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, shader

I'm studying WebGl transformations and I understood the it is possible to build transformation matrices in the application (Javascript file) or in the shader programs (html).

For example I can write all the code about a rotation matrix on the x axis directly in the GLSL program :

```
uniform mat 4 rx;
mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
         0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
         0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
         0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );
```

Or i can write it into the Javascript file and use the :

```
rx = context.getUniformLocation(program, "rx");
```

To specify the value of my uniform.

I would like to understand which is the best choice and why.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok thanks , so if I have to render my image and applying it a dynamic rotation , I have to write the rotation matrice in the JS file and give the uniform to the shader.If I write the rotation matrix in the shader the problem is that for each render phase my application has to access and update the vertex shader ?

Comment: @J.vanLangen Thank you ! Sorry for the question , but do you mean that I have to calculate them in the JS file when you say to calculate them on the cpu ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok and so if my object is a rotating cube , should I compute the calculations in the js code ? Because I have to update the image each "second" so I think that is better not to access every time the shaders but to do everything in the application code.